# Find the origin of a re-booting EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that starts to get setup everytime I terminate it. I was playing around with an ECS cluster, a load balancer etc but I'm quite sure I terminated everything I set up before. Is there any chance to find out what is triggering the EC2 instance everytime? I'm using an AWS Students account so I might me limited when it comes to billing etc. The only thing running is an S3 bucket but that shouldn't trigger any EC2 instance I guess.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an ECS cluster based on EC2 instances (rather than Fargate), you get an auto-scaling group. Deleting the cluster should delete the group.

You can also go to the EC2 page in the Console, pick your EC2 instance, and look at its tags. If you see a tag `aws:autoscaling:groupName`, that means that the instance is being controlled by an auto-scaling group. You can pick "Auto Scaling Groups" in the left-nav of that page, to see the actual group. The group's name will also give you a hint of what created it.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick for me! For some reason the autoscale group wasn't deleted and it was created during some process so I didn't even know it existed.